# .xproj and .json is not recognized in Visual studio

Tags: visual-studio-2015, asp.net-core, dnx

I have VS 2015 and installed the DNX.
But when I open any dnx project in VS , the project is not recognized.

What am I missing here?

I followed the following example and I was able to run the application throw command like but not to open it in VS

https://github.com/aspnet/Home/blob/dev/README.md

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Finally worked by uninstalling all VS and the DNX then reinstall them. 
Dont do repair it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Download and install the [Microsoft ASP.NET and Web Tools 2015](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48738&fa43d42b-25b5-4a42-fe9b-1634f450f5ee=True).

Comment: I did but still not recognizing , I am now reinstalling all the VS2015 .

Comment: Could you tell more about what you see when the error occurs?